# Property preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins is ignored in UIStackView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uistackview

I am trying to make a stack view inside a scroll view that respects the layout margins of the superview. So I am putting `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` to true, and come up with this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sv
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        sv.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 64, bottom: 0, right: 64)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor),
            scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leftAnchor),
            scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.rightAnchor),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leftAnchor),
            view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.rightAnchor),
        ])

        let l = UILabel()
        l.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Itaque his sapiens semper vacabit. An est aliquid, quod te sua sponte delectet? Aliud igitur esse censet gaudere, aliud non dolere. Quasi ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Atque etiam valítudinem, vires, vacuitatem doloris non propter utilitatem solum, sed etiam ipsas propter se expetemus. Naturales divitias dixit parabiles esse, quod parvo esset natura contenta."
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(l)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

However the lorem ipsum text is ignoring the margins of 64 to the left and 64 to the right completely.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a stack view's *arranged subviews* are constrained via the edges of the stack view... not the margins.

You can fix that by setting the stack view's `.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement` property to `true`:

```
let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // add this line
    sv.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true

    return sv
}()
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks!!